# What does merge do in navigation.navigate (React Native)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I don't understand what `merge` does in navigation.navigate

```
navigation.navigate({
   name: 'Home',
   params: { post: postText },
   merge: true,
});
```

Code reference is taken from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine you are on a route or screen called `BlogPage` with the following params

{
title: 'A title',
author: 'keysl'
}

and you navigate into different Blog post using

```
navigation.navigate({
  name: 'BlogPage',
  params: { title: 'B title' },
});
```

So prior to Navigation 5 the default was to merge this, so the code above will produce a page with params like

```
{
  title: 'B title',
  author: 'keysl' // note that keysl is not passed at the code below
}
```

This was not ideal and prone to confusion. So, the React Navigation team removed this default. Though it's useful in different cases.

Now in order to replicate the functionality above the `merge:true` was introduced.

I can't find the migration statement but that's the gist of what it does

Comment: may i know why the name param isnt provided as first argument in the navigate method since according to the docs navigation.navigate(name, params) instead the name is inside the object as shown above

Comment: @NauTxz navigating using an object like the example above was documented as an equivalent option to navigate(name, params) till react-navigation 4.x, for some reason it was removed from version 5.x api documentation, but it's still being used